# send a javascript variable to controller in mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

I have to send a tristate checkBox state to the controller in MVC. Always the post method sends true/false. I want send a int value with three states ( 0,1,-1). How can I send the tristate value to the controller?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ts(cb) {
        if (cb.readOnly) cb.checked=cb.readOnly=false;
        else if (!cb.checked) cb.readOnly = cb.indeterminate = true;
        return (cb.indeterminate ? -1 : cb.checked ? 1 : 0);
    }

</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Transitos", FormMethod.Get))
{
     <table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Sancionado: <input type="checkbox" id="Sancinado" name="Sancionado" onclick="ts(this)" />
        </th>
        <th>
            <input type="submit" value="Buscar" />
        </th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

}

in the Controller I have:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? Sancionado )
{
        var Transitos = from s in db.Transitos
                       select s;

        if(Sancionado != null)
        {
            Transitos = Transitos.Where(x => x.Sancionado == (Sancionado==1 ? true : false));
        }
        return View(Transitos.ToList());
}
```

Comment: did u try <input type="checkbox" id="Sancinado" name="Sancionado" value="1"/>

Comment: Hello, I tried, but I cant see any change. The same result.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ts(cb) {
        if (cb.readOnly) cb.checked=cb.readOnly=false;
        else if (!cb.checked) cb.readOnly = cb.indeterminate = true;
        var Sancionado = (cb.indeterminate ? -1 : cb.checked ? 1 : 0);
        $("#Sancinado").val(Sancionado); 
        $("form").submit(); //find your form and submit use more suit selector then just a "form"
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. With this code, I can send the three values to the server. Also I have more fields to send to the server, as you can see I already have a Razor syntax form. But as you suggestion I have to build a complete form in JavaScript, is right?

Comment: Just one of possible approaches, It is works and it's fine